# Accidentally clicked on "Expulse SD card" on RPI3

Tags: raspbian-stretch

I accidentally clicked on "Expulse SD card" on RPI3 now I don´t have any image I can access Terminal with an SSH but if I try to connect it to my TV with an HDMI  or with a remote desktop I don´t get any image.

Is there a line command to fix this?

I was also trying to run this tutorial but I quit because of lack of memory on my SD. But I ran some of those commands.

https://docs.eltechs.com/install-and-configure-exagear-desktop/how-to-install-exagear-desktop-trial

Comment: have you turned it off and on again?

Comment: `Is there a line command to fix this?` fix what? you say you quit running the tutorial, but there's 5 steps involved, at what step did you stop?